# How can I see all my installed program in Ubuntu from command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can I see all my installed program in Ubuntu  from command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dpkg --get-selections

This will send it to a file for you:

dpkg --get-selections > installed-software

from this thread on Ubuntu forums:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=261366

Comment: How can i add program not at this list?

Comment: apt-get, it's pretty easy:
https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/apt-get.html
There's also aptitude which gives you a few other features:
https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/aptitude.html

Comment: Its true only if i didn't downloaded program manually to ubuntu, I want to know how to do that to manually  downloaded program please

Comment: Here's a tutorial that mentions manually downloaded programs: 
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installingsoftwareold

Comment: Other .tar.gz  - I have, zend studio

Answer (score 1):

If you hit the Tab button at the command line in most linux distrobutions, it will list everything you can call from the terminal. It'll prompt you something like "Do you want to list all these packages?". Of course you do! Then it'll list em.

As for if Ubuntu does this, I do not recall. I don't have an ubuntu machine handy or I would test this beforehand. Hope that works for you!

Comment: Oh, shoot... Just recalled that you may have to tap it twice or 3 times depending on your distro.

Comment: I get 2,000 programs